# How to concatenate different string after each dictionary entry

Tags: python, string, dictionary, printing

```
{0: {'Name': 'Tom', 'Age': 20},
 1: {'Name': 'Joseph', 'Age': 21},
 2: {'Name': 'Krish', 'Age': 19},
 3: {'Name': 'John', 'Age': 18}}
```

I want to print each element of the dictionary followed by a string concatenated as shown below. it is easy to print a same string concatenated after each element but i dont get to understand how to have a different string concatenated after each dictionary element.

A sample output is as shown below:

```
0 : {'Name': 'Tom', 'Age': 20} is more similar to
1 : {'Name': 'Joseph', 'Age': 21} than to
2 : {'Name': 'Krish', 'Age': 19} than to
3 : {'Name': 'John', 'Age': 18}}
```

Comment: what is the basis to use these strings and where do you get it from?

Comment: The output needs to be printed in this manner. there is no variable carrying string its just a print statement, i was just wondering if it is possible to concatenate the output in the print statement intelligently. Any inputs are appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```py
my_dict = {...}
outputs = ['is more similar to', 'than to', 'than to', '']
i = 0
for key, val in my_dict.items():
    print(str(key) + ':', val, outputs[i])
    i += 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. let me check it once. just wondering meanwhile, any optimized way possible to write it in lesser line , i mean without having the list defined. because if i have to print 'thank to' 10 times, i would need to have it as 10 elements. i can also do something like 'than to'*10 but was just wondering if there is any other optimized way

Comment: this idea works but any idea on how to get rid of the last 'than to'. for instance if you see the 3rd index there is no than to in the end

Comment: Kindly let me know if there is an optimized way of writing this. it would be of great help.

Comment: Hi @MohammedNadeem - try this:
`[print(str(list(my_dict.keys())[i]) + ':', list(my_dict.values())[i], outputs[i]) for i in range(len(my_dict))]`